# Installing a forked react component library with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, reactjs, npm

I am trying to `npm install` a fork of a good project with a lot of flaws https://github.com/codyc4321/react-data-components. We need our own copy of it and to make changes, so I forked it and deleted it from the repo.

```
cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ rm -rf node_modules/react-data-components/

cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ atom .

cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ npm i https://github.com/codyc4321/react-data-components
rehub-portal@1.0.0 /Users/cchilders/work_projects/myproject
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY coffee-script@1.x
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.0
└── react-data-components@1.1.1  (git+https://github.com/codyc4321/react-data-components.git#bfa230d806c59f4703346a8377b2e1938152cefd)

npm WARN coffee-loader@0.7.3 requires a peer of coffee-script@1.x but none was installed.
npm WARN react-simpletabs@0.7.0 requires a peer of react@0.12.x - 1.x but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN rehub-portal@1.0.0 No repository field.

cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ npm i --save coffee-script react
rehub-portal@1.0.0 /Users/cchilders/work_projects/myproject
├── coffee-script@1.12.7 
└─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.1
  └── create-react-class@15.6.0 

npm WARN react-simpletabs@0.7.0 requires a peer of react@0.12.x - 1.x but none was installed.
npm WARN rehub-portal@1.0.0 No repository field.

cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ npm i --save coffee-script react@15.6.1
rehub-portal@1.0.0 /Users/cchilders/work_projects/myproject
├── coffee-script@1.12.7 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.6.1

npm WARN react-simpletabs@0.7.0 requires a peer of react@0.12.x - 1.x but none was installed.
npm WARN rehub-portal@1.0.0 No repository field.

cchilders:~/work_projects/myproject (feature/investigate-fixing-react-data-components-table) 
$ node server-dev.js 


...

ERROR in ./client/components/tables/OrderMetricsDataTable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-data-components' in '/Users/cchilders/work_projects/myproject/client/components/tables'
 @ ./client/components/tables/OrderMetricsDataTable.js 64:16-48
 @ ./client/controllers/OrderMetricsController.js
 @ ./client/main.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client/main.js

ERROR in ./client/components/tables/GenericTable.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-data-components' in '/Users/cchilders/work_projects/myproject/client/components/tables'
 @ ./client/components/tables/GenericTable.js 67:16-48
 @ ./client/controllers/checkoutEventLogController.js
 @ ./client/main.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client ./client/main.js

 ...
```

If I delete this and install the same code with `npm i react-data-components`, it works. The code is the same because I haven't made my changes yet, and I'm surprised the same code doesn't install. Putting his code inside our project (but not in node modules) caused a syntax error with the word `static` and probably because there's some TypeScript in his code.

How do I install this fork with `npm` so I can update my changes when I make them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the project to a local directory and then run `npm install /path/to/cloned/directory`

Comment: hmm. would you happen to know why that works? the recommendation was here http://remarkablemark.org/blog/2016/09/19/npm-install-from-github/